# Xamarin.Forms : issue with Android.Graphics after reinstall Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I developed a Xamarin.forms app  for Android running Visual Studio 16.9.3
Everything worked fine until reinstalling Windows 10 and Visual Studio 16.11.11 Preview 1.0I
Now I have an error in a view of the main project:

```
using Android.Graphics
```

is not recognized:  Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Graphics' does not exist in the 'Android' namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) .

However, in the MainActivity.cs file, this code

```
Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 47, 56, 40));
```

is not a problem.
I tried to follow the instructions given by Microsoft regarding Compiler Error CS0234, but to no avail: I don't see how to use the Object Browser to inspect an assembly and verify whether it contains the types that I expect it to contain.

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?
Thank you very much.

Warning in the Solution explorer :
[image: Problem with Mono.Android]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace MemoCourses.ViewModels
{
    public static class ImageResizer
    {
        static ImageResizer()
        {
        }

        public static async Task<byte[]> ResizeImage(byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
        {
            return ResizeImageAndroid(imageData, width, height);
        }

        public static byte[] ResizeImageAndroid(byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
        {
            // Load the bitmap
            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            //
            float heightRequest = 0;
            float widthRequest = 0;
            //
            var Height = originalImage.Height;
            var Width = originalImage.Width;
            //
            if (Height > Width)
            {
                heightRequest = height;
                float ratio = Height / height;
                widthRequest = Width / ratio;
            }
            else
            {
                widthRequest = width;
                float ratio = Width / width;
                heightRequest = Height / ratio;
            }



            //
            Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)widthRequest, (int)heightRequest, false);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                resizedImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        //
    }
}
```

[image: Add Reference]

Comment: you can't use Android.Graphics in the shared project.  Do you actually need that namespace for something you are doing in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't change anything to the code, and it worked fine before reinstalling Visual Studio. I need Android.Graphics because I use the Bitmap type several times. Example: Bitmap originaImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length); Which obviously gives me an error...

Comment: AFAIK the only way to make this work would be to directly reference the relevant Xamarin.Android.dll from your project.  But this will mean your shared project will never be cross-platform, which is one of the key benefits of using Xamarin Forms.  The "correct" way to include platform specific functions in shared code is to use DependencyService or custom renderers

Comment: About the first solution, how to directly reference the relevant Xamarin.Android.dll from my project? (I have only an Android Project). And about the second solution, how do I go about using DependencyService? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Use “Add Reference” like you would to add a dll to any VS project.  Lookup “DependencyService” in the Xamarin docs

Comment: I couldn't add reference, nor use the DependencyService, it's too difficult for me. I noticed this warning: Warning MSB3245 Unable to resolve this reference. Unable to find assembly "Mono.Android". Verify that the assembly exists on disk. If it's required by your code, you might get compiler errors. Is this the origin of the problem? However, the Mono.Android.dll file exists in several folders : However, the Mono.Android.dll file exists in several folders, including C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v10.0

Comment: it would help a great deal if you actually posted the code that requires the Android Bitmap type

Comment: I added the code and a screenshot of the warning in solution explorer

Comment: this should be very straightforward to implement as a DependencyService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to use the Bitmap in the share project, the visual studio will notify me to add the reference Mono.Android.dll. Such as:
[image]

And then when I clicked the `Add reference to 'Mono.Android.dll'`, it worked well.

In addition, I had checked the path of `Mono.Android.dll` in the forms part and the android part, they are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems simple, but my Visual Studio 2019 does not offer me to add a reference to Mono.Android.dll. When I try to add it manually from the solution manager, I get a message telling me that the reference is invalid or not supported.

Comment: Have you checked the path of the reference you added is same as it in the android part?@MarcelDelhaye

Comment: Thank you Liyun Zhang. This is the solution !

Answer (score 0):

I checked and got this:

Android :

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll
```

Shared :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll
```

The path is not the same. So I replaced Community with preview in the  MemoCoureses.csproj shared project file, did a regeneration, and everything works fine. Thank you very very much!